# iOS App with this Features? Possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm trying to develop an application with prohibited features for iOS. Swift.

I just want to know how possible they are (to make and to submit).

1 - Silencing the phone: I've seen this question in a lot of posts and the all says NO, No posible and will be rejected but... how about this app? This app silence the phone (putting ringer volume to 0) -> https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/autosilent-automatically-silence-your-phone/id474777148?mt=8
This app was summited a few years ago, i think when Celestial Framework and submitting apps with Private Frameworks was something possible, not now, so, is this possible?

2 - Blocking calls: I know since iOS 10 you can block calls with CallKit but, you need to give XCProvider a list of numbers to block. I want to block all the calls, can i give all the numbers? in the world?.

3 - Respond blocked calls with an SMS back: I can not have information about the incoming call (phone number) to send some request to a web API so it can send a message to the caller. Or do i?.

Thank you very much for all your responses...

Comment: "possible" probably. Allowed based on Apple's app store guidelines? Definitely No for 2 and 3, I'm guessing the app from 1 is using some sort of audio or video session hack to get this to work.

Comment: Start a cellular provider.  Then you can implement these features from the provider side and expose a REST endpoint for configuring from the app.  Alternatively, develop the app in partnership with a cellular provider (it would be easier to partner with a T-Mobile than get Apple to change policies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your second and third point are impossible at the current situation.
You could give XCProvider a list with all number but that list would have a length of about 10^13 entries.
Apple doesn't provide a public API to recognize blocked calls and thats why you third point seems to be impossible too.